# Javax Validation: deeply nested validation not working

Tags: java, validation, quarkus, lombok

It seems that deeply nested validation doesn't work on a very simple example (using quarkus & lombok) using javax validation:

```
import lombok.Data;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Data
public class AModel {

    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private BModel bModel;

    @Data
    public static class BModel {

        @NotNull
        @Valid
        private CModel cModel;

    }

    @Data
    public static class CModel {

        @NotNull
        private int number;

    }

}
```

`AModel` class validations work without problem.
`BModel` class validations work without problem.
`CModel` class validations are fully ignored (e.g. @NotNull for number).

Am I doing something wrong, or am I hitting some sort of bug / limitation (very highly doubt that)?

Thanks

Comment: An `int` can never be `null`, only zero. So either use `Integer`, or use something like `@Min`.

Comment: such a bad mistake from my side. Thank you :)